A motor-driven, adjustable spring-tension device
Setup: A spring that is attached to a motor on its left side with a cable. The distance between the motor and the spring must remain the same, meaning it cannot be put in tension  !
The right side is the spring attached to a welded nut... Inside the spring, screwed in from the right, is an Archemidus-type wheel that fits right inside the spring, this occupies part of the spring, that now is 'limited' in its spring-length.  This Archemidus-wheel is attached to a regular bolt, that is screwed through the welded nut.
The length that this Archemidus-wheel is turned inside the spring, determines how much 'free' spring is left and the shorter, obviously the more power the motor needs to exert to tension the spring.
I need to turn the bolt with an electric motor to adjust the 'tension' of the spring, but while not adjusting the total length of the spring... And all needs to be rather small...

This is not 100% clear, could you draw a diagram?

what's a worm-type wheel?

There are small, low-RPM electrical step motors that couple with a variety of threaded load shafts. They have mounting brackets to be secured to a base.
You can replace the welded nut with this step motor that is bolted down and adjus the free length of your spring by rotating the bolt.

